# По сюда / посюда

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, наречия, разговорная-речь

Как правильно? Думаю, что, так как здесь *ю* ударная и можно также сказать *посюдова*, надо писать *посюда*.

`Снег был по сюда / посюда!`

Comment: Снег был пасюда. - Да не пасюдкай мне! Покуда был, отвечай! - Посюдова, по сюда вот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• Вот что нашлось в словаре русских народных говоров [(стр. 258–259)](https://azbyka.ru/otechnik/assets/uploads/slovar-russkih-narodnyh-govorov/Slovar_govora-30.pdf).

***Посю́да́*** и ***посю́д***, наречие.
**1.** По этому месту, здесь. Посюда. Тобол., 1919. *Давай посюда проезжай*. Иркут. Свердл. *Иди посюда, все здеся ходят.* Перм. Арх. = Посю́д. *Потам шли или посюд?*
Коми АССР, 1957.
**2.** Посюда́. По эту сторону. *Черемхово там, у лахт етых. Посюда
от Ямы-то.* Мурман., 1979.

***Посюда́е*** и ***посюдя́е***, наречие. Немного в эту сторону, сюда, поближе. *Иди посюдяе и выйдешь.*

***Посю́дова***, наречие. По этому месту, здесь. *Да вот посюдова идите,
как раз и дойдете.* Камен. Свердл., 1983.

***Посю́ль***, наречие. До какого места, докуда. *Посюль раньше доходила полая вода.* Трубч., Брян., 1939.

***Посю́ля***, наречие. По этому месту, здесь. *Вы ступайте посюля, туто короче будет.* Камен. Свердл., 1983.

• *Тогда вернулись они, я еще вот **посюда** был, а теперь вернутся они, я уже вот **посюда**...* (Александра Николаенко. Небесный почтальон Федя Булкин). [[Книга](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=78572&p=1) — лауреат премии "Русский Букер".]

■ Конечно, этих слов вы не найдете ни в одном в орфографическом словаре (хотя разговорные наречия ***поку́да, доку́да*** и ***досю́да*** имеются).
Но в обиходном устном языке они присутствуют. И если уж надо написать (передать, например, чью-то особенную речь), то так: *Снег был посюда!*